# How to configure apache to serve both RoR and Flask on the same machine?

Tags: apache2

I have a dedicated machine I use for testing. At the moment it's running a Rails (2.3) app over Apache and Passenger. I would also like to simultaneously serve a Flask application using the same machine and a different url if possible. Here's what I currently have for my `httpd.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /path/to/rails-app/public
  PassengerDefaultUser railsuser
  RailsEnv testing
  # .. some misc apache config
</VirtualHost>
```

How should I modify it to serve two different urls (on a local network) with one serving the Rails app and the other serving Flask? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your OP, you're setting the handling for the default url.

For your second virtual web server, just use a specific host name in the config that is a second host name for the same machine. This is called "name-based" virtual hosting. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting).

Remember that multiple hostnames can resolve to the same IP address.

You can use the full dns system if you want, just specify your local network address (192.168.xxx) -- the url will not work for machines not on your local network.

More info will be available at the webmasters SO site.

**A [post](http://www.geeksengine.com/article/apache-multiple-local-websites.html) with instructions**